# WinRT: new view/window does not inherit App.RequestedTheme

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, win-universal-app

Is it possible to use themes and new-windows together in a WinRT or Universal Windows App?

The RequestedTheme of the app is not "inherited" by secondary views, for example...

```
async Task OpenNewWindow()
{
    var currentTheme = App.Current.RequestedTheme; // Set to Dark in the App's constructor
    int newViewId = -1;

    await newView.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        // Next line shows theme reset to Light and cannot be changed to match the main view's theme
        var themeForNewView = App.Current.RequestedTheme; 

        // Code omitted here to create the new Frame

        Window.Current.Content = newFrame;
        Window.Current.Activate();

        var coreWindow = CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread();
            newViewId = ApplicationView.GetApplicationViewIdForWindow(coreWindow);
    }

    // Display the new view and window - APPEARS WITH LIGHT THEME, NOT THE THEME SET IN THE ORIGINAL APP CONSTRUCTOR
    var currentViewId = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Id;
    var viewShown = await ApplicationViewSwitcher.TryShowAsStandaloneAsync(
        newViewId, ViewSizePreference.UseHalf, currentViewId, ViewSizePreference.UseHalf);
}
```

(Sample code based on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn582023.aspx)

Comment: I can understand your code for creating a new window, but do you want to set one `RequestedTheme` for all window? To do this, in an UWP app, you can define this property in the App.xaml file.

Comment: Thanks Grace.  Setting the RequestedTheme property in the App constructor should be the same as setting it in the Xaml.  I need to set it programmatically as in the full code it is being read from the user's preferences stored for the app.

Answer (score 0):

My UWP app use multi-view(window) style, and the main and sub windows can use the same theme.
Here is a code of my app [F10 image bbs browser](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/f10-image-bbs-browser/9nblggh1ntrd). The app have one main window - showing thread catalog and threads, and multiple image window.

```
    private async Task<ViewLifetimeControl> createImagePageAsync(string url)
    {
        ViewLifetimeControl viewControl = null;
        await CoreApplication.CreateNewView().Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            var f10url = new F10Url(url);
            viewControl = ViewLifetimeControl.CreateForCurrentView();
            viewControl.Title = f10url.threadTitle;
            viewControl.Url = url;
            viewControl.StartViewInUse();

            var frame = new Frame();

            frame.RequestedTheme = GetSavedElementTheme(); // <<------- here

            RegistTitleBarColor();
            frame.Navigate(typeof(ImagePage), viewControl);
            Window.Current.Content = frame;
            Window.Current.Activate();
            ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Title = viewControl.Title;
        });

        ((F10Client)F10Client.Current).SecondaryViews.Add(viewControl);

        return viewControl;
    }
```

Yes, just set a same requested theme to the new frame. GetSavedElementTheme() just returns the theme saved in app preference - Windows.UI.Xaml.ElementTheme.Default, Dark or Light.

I hope the code helps you.

Note - my code is based on Microsoft's 
[Multiple views sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/MultipleViews).